# I have one OnClickListener inside another, but my activity stops working if I click the first button

Tags: android

I have one OnClickListener inside another, but my activity stops working if I click the first button.

This is my code :

```
addNewCard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),CustomDialog.class);
            startActivity(i);
            launchCamera(view);*/

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogbox);
            EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.enter_name);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

           okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);

            okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    launchCamera(view);

                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Thank you if you could help me, some idea ...

Comment: post error log here.

Comment: okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your error

```
okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
```

**assuming** your button is in dialog layout, so it should be

```
okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!
It worked.
I understand that I needed dialog because otherwise it would be looking for the button from the main activity, right ?

Answer (score 0):

In case of using dialog if you are using onClickListener than it shold be like DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

```
     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogbox);
    EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.enter_name);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);

    okButton.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            launchCamera(view);

        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
}
```